# Unity2D animation stops after it finished first animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

```
void attacking()
    {
        if ((_attack.attackk || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) && spr.flipX==false)
        {
            anim.Play("SlashR");

        }if((_attack.attackk || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) && spr.flipX==true){
            anim.Play("SlashL");
        }

        if (health.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x <= 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool("death", true);
            isDeath = true;
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("death", false);
            isDeath = false;
        }
    }
```

İ'm trying to make a 2D hack&slash game,and that's why i need a combat system.
So,to do this i wanted to make two animation,SlashR is for right sword and SlashL is for left sword.What i want to do is that if i press mouse button and my character is turn Right then will play SlashR anim,and vice versa.
But when i press mouse button(flipX=false) SlashR animation plays only for one times.After one animation is finished,animation stops completely and vice versa.
But there's weird thing as well,when i turn my character left and after that turn right,SlashR animation is playing again.
Note: Loop time unchecked for SlashR and SlashL

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your state-diagram from the Animator that you are using?

Comment: yes,here is https://pasteboard.co/IrJjIPJD.png.  İ don't used animator to these slash animation since animator is causing animation tearing problems,so i wanted to use scripting for animations SlashR and SlashL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your State-diagram from your Animator, your `SlashR` and `SlashL` state does not go back to `Idle` after they are done.
This will cause the slashing-states to stay in their current state after the animation is done.

Make a state-transition from `SlashR` and `SlashL` to `Idle` (or whatever state you want) and it should fix the problem.

### Edit

> But there's weird thing as well,when i turn my character left and after that turn right,SlashR animation is playing again.

That is because in your

```
        if ((_attack.attackk || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) && spr.flipX==false)
    {
        anim.Play("SlashR");

    }if((_attack.attackk || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) && spr.flipX==true){
        anim.Play("SlashL");
    }
```

you do not check if the player is currently attacking first.
This results in the other animation to immediately start playing when the player moves left-right while it is attacking.

**The solution is to properly make use of your animators** as so:
[image: Image of how your animator should look like]

And your new code should be:

```
if ((_attack.attackk || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) && spr.flipX==false) {
     anim.SetTrigger("SlashR");
} else if((_attack.attackk || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) && spr.flipX==true){
    anim.SetTrigger("SlashL");
}
```

Comment: But when i turn my character left then SlashR animation'll be able to play.So,likewise turning left and right make animations reset.

Comment: @ShooterLensAim I edited my answer. Should resolve the issue

Comment: Hi,thank you,and works perfect nearly.But when i press mouse button consecutive,slash animation doesn't play sometimes.as if there's a bug.

Comment: Can you make sure that there is no exit time from Idle to any of the slash states? Otherwise its really just a bug that I encounter from time to time to and it is really annoying. Hopefully someone who knows can post a solution to the bug.

Comment: Hi again,i fixed that problem by change Input.GetMouseButtonDown to Input.GetMouseButton.Yes it's like magic :D But i don't know again why slash animation doesn't work perfectly with Input.GetMouseButtonDown.Yes it may a bug,or i am idiot.

Answer (score 1):

Please examine the image.

You can right click the state and select make transition etc.

[image: Make Transition]

Use the transitions tool in the Animator state machine.
You have to make transition between slashR to idle and idle to slashR and same thing for slashL.

**For example:**
if you want to change state you can set the boolean true like this,

```
 anim.SetBool ("SlashL", true);
```

Do not forget to hasExit time box.

When exit time is ticked,if the animation is completed then the next animation is played.
If Has Exit Time is checked, this value represents the exact time at which the transition can take effect

Comment: İ did so,but at this time slash animation doesn't play when I click repeatedly.Everything is good when i press button for 3 seconds apart.But i want to play animation whenever press mouse button.https://pasteboard.co/IrJvBnP.png

Comment: Check hasExit time box @ShooterLensAim

Comment: hasExit time is unchecked on all of states.Here's https://pasteboard.co/IrJxdHx.png